# java desktop and web application using the same filepath

Tags: java, web-applications, desktop-application, filepath

I wrote a desktop java application with a class (say ClassA) that reads the content of a file, processes it and returns some results. The filename was specified relative to the project using

File input = new File("config.xml");

Now, I want to upgrade the project into a web project. I wrote a servlet which calls the same java class (i.e. ClassA) for reading the content of the same file but this time I get an error message saying file not found.

How do I refactor my code so that both the desktop and the web versions run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the file config.xml into the proper location on the web server e.g. public_html/www/

The "working directory" of a web application is different - depends on the configuration of the web server you are deploying it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you read a file without specifying a path, it is read from the current dir, which you can access with System.getProperty("user.dir");

So you can try to find out what value is returned by System.getProperty("user.dir") in your web app and place the file there.
But this may differ depending on the environment and servlet server (Tomcat etc.) and may be not a reliable solution.

Another way is to change your code, so it reads the file from the  user.home directory and place the file there.